# Stripe payment Integration with .net core Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, stripe-payments

I want to setup Stripe payment in my .Net core 6.0 web application that ask customer for their credit card via stripe to pay the amount.
I want to do the payment at Save button.

**View:**

```
@model SalesInvoiceModel
<h2>Create Invoice</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateInvoice", "SalesInvoice", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TotalAmount"></label>
        <input asp-for="TotalAmount" class="form-control" id="TotalAmount" readonly />
        <span asp-validation-for="TotalAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public class SalesInvoiceController : Controller
{
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public SalesInvoiceController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {   _configuration = configuration;  }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateInvoice(SalesInvoiceModel model)
        {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_AddInvoiceDetails", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", model.Id);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", model.TotalAmount);
                        connection.Open();
                        int userId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                        TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Invoice created successfully.";
                        return RedirectToAction("InvoiceList", "SalesInvoice");
                    
                }}}
```

Comment: If you are looking for a guide that walks you through how to get one-time payments and sell fixed-price subscriptions and provides an example of a well-working integration with Stripe, look at the demo https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 1):

In order to accept payment with Stripe, you have two main options:

1. Stripe Checkout Session: iss a pre-built, hosted payment solution by Stripe. It provides a secure, customizable, and mobile-friendly payment form that can handle the entire payment process. You simply redirect customers to Stripe's hosted checkout page, where they can enter their payment details and complete the payment.

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment
- https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart?lang=dotnet

2. Stripe Payment Element: is a set of flexible, customizable UI components that you can use to build your payment forms within your web application. These components are designed to be adaptable and responsive, providing an excellent user experience on both desktop and mobile devices. With Stripe Elements, you can create a fully custom payment flow with a higher degree of control and flexibility.

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=dotnet

Comment: Thank you so much, I have configured the stripe payment.